# QML/Javascript: Adding Self-Referencing Attribute to Subarrays Inside Nested var Matching Some Identifier

Tags: javascript, recursion, append, qml, var

I would like to recurse through a nested varlist named "data", stored in QML as a `var`.  It contains an attribute named `"delegates": [  { ... }, ... , { ... } ]` which declares some properties for some delegates.  If one of these attribute sublists contains an attribute "`"data"` I have another sublevel that can be traversed to by the action of that particular delegate.

What I would like to do is to create a function to recursively append to my varlist (`"data"` sublevels), with pointer to the parent level whenever a sublevel matching that name detected (`"data"`) is detected.  For instance if `data.delegates[0].data` exists, I would like to append to it the equivalent of `data.delegates[0].data.parentPointer: data`; if `data.delegates[0].data.delegates[0].data` exists, I would like to append the equivalent of `data.delegates[0].data.delegates[0].data.parentPointer: data.delegates[0].data` and so on...

I'm not particularly concerned about (the computational) cost, as this is a one time event in the `Component.onCompleted` of a `pragma Singleton` and nesting is only a few levels deep at most.

This is more of a Javascript problem, I believe, as I believe the way to automate the creation of the self-referential pointers is via some sort of recursive `function` call (which is by definition in Javascript for QML).  I know how to do append operations on simple `var` sets in Javascript in QML:

```
function appendStuff(myVar) {
   var temp = myVar
   temp.push("stuff")
   myVar = temp
}
```

and I know I can conditionally check in Javascript for named attributes w/in a `var` like:

```
if (typeof currentLevel.data !== "undefined") {
  //do stuff....
}
```

However, I'm kind of hung up on the recursive aspect -- how to rebuild a multilevel array -- whilst properly keeping track of my position in the original array, until my edited version is completed.  I also realize I probably will need my edited version to be referring to itself when it comes to `"parentPointer"`, which gets kind of tricky.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you include input data and expected output data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign new fields to a JS Object, you can just use `myjsobject['newprop'] = value`.

So a simple recursive function to create e.g. a double linked list, would be this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 400; height: 450

    function foo(depth, ref) {
        var a = { value: depth }
        if (depth !== 0) {
            a['next'] = foo(depth - 1, a)
        }
        if (ref) a['pred'] = ref
        return a
    }

    property var test: foo(10)

    Component.onCompleted: console.log(test.value, test.next.value, test.next.pred.value)
}
```